# Setting a PFObject Value with Segmented Control

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, uisegmentedcontrol

Real simply -

I'm trying to create a group sharing app that allows users to create a public or private group.  I have create a "CreateTableViewController" which saves an image, group name, and comments as a PFObject within Parse. This all works fine.  What I want to do however, is add a Segmented Control with 2 segments (1-public, 2-private) and incorporate that into my existing PFObject method.  If a user clicks "public", then the PFObject is saved with a value of public or vice versa.

As a beginner I'm sure this is an easy solve, so please share some wisdom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UISegmentedControl` has a property to get the selected segment, you can use this on save to determine which value the user selected.

So whenever a user hits the save button in your app, get the value of that property (an int) like so for example `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.

To automatically get notified about changes to that control, you can add a target and selector for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to your segmented control. Whenever the selected value changes, this method is called and you can call the save method of your choice on your `PFObject`.

```
[mySegmentedControl 
    addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(myMethod) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

*UISegmentedControl Documentation*
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex